# Can't get array of object from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, axios

I am writing a simple website which display a list of object from server

**server: index.js**

```
var db = [{ username: 'admin', password: '1234', email: 'admin@gmail.com'}];
app.get('/getListAccount', (req, res)=>{
  res.send(db);
})
```

**display: list.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';

class Transaction extends React.Component{

  render(){
    var {listUser} = this.props;
    var xhtml = listUser != null ? <p>{listUser.map((e, i)=><p key={i}>{e.username}</p>)}</p>: <p>No user</p>;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Transaction</h1>
        {xhtml}
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
    var {dispatch} = this.props;
    axios.get('/getListAccount')
    .then( ({data}) => {
      dispatch({
       type: 'INIT_LIST',
       mang: data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
}

module.exports = connect(function(state){
  return {listUser: state.listUser}
})(Transaction);
```

Here is reducer for `listUser` state: 
**app.js**

```
var listUser = (state = [{username: null, password: null, email: null}], 
action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'INIT_LIST':
    {
      return {...action.mang};
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

But when I run it always throw this error
`listUser.map is not a function`. Why and how can I fix it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are you getting in response (i.e. data in componentDidMount)? Can you check your network tab and tell?

Comment: map is a function on the Array prototype. so it's better to check if Array.isArray(listUser), rather than listUser != null.

Comment: @AjayGaur response for `getListAccount` is `[{"username":"admin","password":"1234","email":"admin@gmail.com"}]` but it still throw `listUser.map is not a function`

Answer (score 2):

In your reducer, try doing

```
case 'INIT_LIST':
    {
      return action.mang;
    }
```

The problem here is that you're putting an array in state (default state as well) and you're converting it back to the object.

Comment: Oh, it works like a charm, thank u so much @Ajay Gaur.

Comment: @TuấnTrầnDuy glad it worked but a better way would be putting an array of objects in your state and using the lodash map function to so that you can get away with any errors.